# How Java 8+ infers method reference as consumer?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I was exploring some new things related to JDK 8, in particular the Refrence Methods and Iterable's new `forEach` method as below:-

```
public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] testArgs = new String[]{"test","123","456"};
        Arrays.asList(testArgs).forEach(Runner::test);
    }

    public static String test(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
        return s;
    }

}
```

This works as required, but as i see the `forEach` method in the `java.lang.Iterable` it is like below, accepting and expecting `Consumer<? super T> action`

```
default void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(action);
    for (T t : this) {
        action.accept(t);
    }
}
```

Now coming to the question -> how is the JDK considering `method reference` as the `Consumer` type?

Comment: `main` is a function that accepts a single argument and returns void. That seems to satisfy `Consumer` fine. It isn't all method references being interpreted as consumers, it's just that `main` is appropriate in that context.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Doesn't it return `s`?

Comment: It technically does, but the return value can be ignored.  Thus it is as good as void.

Comment: @GBlodgett There's two `main`s. It's likely referencing the entry point `main`, making it recursive.

Comment: Let me shape it better, ignore the overridden main consider as different name

Comment: @kakabali If it still works, then this would be a duplicate.

Comment: yes you can replace lambda with method reference, only the rule is method arguments should match ( and return type in some cases) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

Comment: but am asking here how does it infers it as consumer? so that should not be duplicate :-) ?? @GBlodgett? @Carcigenicate

Comment: It infers it as `Consumer` because _you_ told it to do so. As long as the compiler can make a fitting lambda from it (in this case `s -> {test(s);}`, it will work. You can use the same method reference for other interfaces too (like `Function<String, String>` would also work here)

Comment: @kakabali Because you passed it to a method that expects a consumer and (from the docs for consumer) *This is a functional interface and can therefore be used as the assignment target for a lambda expression or method reference.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java-8 compiler looks at the method declarations involved:

- `public void forEach(Consumer<? super T>` in interface `Iterable<T>`
- `public void accept(T t)` in interface `Consumer<T>`
- `public static String test(String)` in your class `Runner`

From all these it concludes that `Consumer<String>` will fit.

Hence, it expands the method reference `Runner::test`
to an implementation of interface `Consumer<String>` which delegates
to the method `test(String)`.

The line

```
Arrays.asList(testArgs).forEach(Runner::test);
```

is expanded to something equivalent to this:

```
Arrays.asList(testArgs).forEach(new Consumer<String>() {        
    @Override
    public void accept(String t) {
        test(t);
    }
});
```

Actually it does not exactly the above, but uses some JVM optimization
to avoid the anonymous class overhead.
But diving into these JVM details would lead too far here.

Comment: so in all cases depending on the need it infers your reference method to some Functional interface?

Comment: @kakabali Yes, you are right.